# div take all available height

Tags: html, css, reactjs, height

I'm using the following HTML

```
<div className="App">
    <div className="AppMenu">
        Menu
    </div>
    <div className="AppContainer">
        Test
    </div>
</div>
```

and this CSS:

```
.App {
  min-height: 100vh !important;
  max-height: 100vh !important;
  height: 100vh !important;
  background-color: red;
}

.AppMenu {
  background-color: blue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.AppContainer {
  background-color: green;
}
```

how can I set / calc AppContainer size to take all heigh => 100vh-(AppMenu height)
with CSS (or js) ?

Comment: what is the issue you having? you already have 100vh? do you mean the overflow? That is cause by the default margins of the body which needs to be resetted. Also for HTML use `class` not `className` which is invalid HTML.

Comment: @tacoshy, maybe the author is using `react`

Comment: yes maybe, but in this cases it should be tagged as such.

Comment: Hello. You have been given the answers to your question. Please, choose one answer from many that helped you, and mark the answer with a tick to the left of the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

You already using the full height of a screen with `100vh`. There is no need to use a nuke like `!important` which nearly always just mask the issue instead of solving it. Also `min-height: 100vh;` + `max-height: 100vh;` can be considered as bad coding. In this case you want a definite height of 100vh which is done by `height: 100vh;`. So you having 3 lines of code where you actually only would need 1.

The issue that you get a scrollbar and the screen is overflowing is caused by the default body margin. The element will be 100vh tall and use the default body amrgin which will cause an document height of more then 100vh. Therefor simply reset the default body amrgin to 0 with: `body { margin: 0; }`

However with that soultion you will have a potencial overflow issue. So you should either set an `overflow rule` to the container or use `min-height` instead.

To have the the `AppContainer` fill the remaining height there are multiple ways to solve it. The easiest way to solve it would be the sue of a CSS-Grid with `grid-template-rows: min-content auto;`. That way, the Menu will take up as much space as needed and the remining height will be used be the `AppContainer`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.App {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content auto;
}

.AppMenu {
  background-color: blue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.AppContainer {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class="AppMenu">
    Menu
  </div>
  <div class="AppContainer">
    Test
  </div>
</div>
```

Last but not least. for HTML you have to use `class` not `className` which would be invalid HTML as this attribute doesnt exist.

Comment: class / className is mistake cause I'm using react + typescript. Currently AppContainer doesn't take all available height. How can I resolved it ?

Comment: Sorry missed the actual aprt of the question. I updated my anwser. I would eprsonally solve it with a CSS-Grid, there multiple solutions but CSS-Grid can do this cleanly without much coding.

Answer (score 0):

These lines make no sense. This can be removed:

```
max-height: 100vh !important;
height: 100vh !important;
```

To stretch `.AppContainer` to the full free height, use rule `flex: 1`:

```
.AppContainer {
  ...
  flex: 1;
}
```

And for the `.App`, set the `flex` rules. Like this:

```
.App {
  ... 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

**Flex has very good browser support.**

Do you need such a result?

```css
.App {
  min-height: 100vh !important;
  background-color: red;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.AppMenu {
  background-color: blue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.AppContainer {
  background-color: green;
  
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
    <div class="AppMenu">
        Menu
    </div>
    <div class="AppContainer">
        Test
    </div>
</div>
```